# justify-content does not work for css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Why justify-content: space-between doesnt work in this case? I want to push the last item to the right edge and center the middle one.

```css
div{
  background: lightblue;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
}

main{
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5rem 0rem;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
```

```html
<main>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to look like?

Comment: Make items to take full width of the container with space-between. So the third item in the row goes to maximum right edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but instead of using fractional unit `fr`, you should use a fixed size `8rem` (aligned with your box size).

`fr` has been stretching your grid box, so that's why you cannot apply `justify-content` without spare space.

```css
div{
  background: lightblue;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
}

main{
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 8rem); /*Modify 1fr to 8rem*/
  gap: 5rem 0rem;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
```

```html
<main>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

main{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px; /*Make the grid smaller than the container*/
  gap: 5rem 0rem;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
```

```html
<main>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</main>
```

//you must use percent not absolute